# MySQLi join using date(now()) in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am running this query in phpmyadmin and it works fine. But on running it in `joshcam's MySQLi Database` class it gets wrong data
Query:

```
SELECT 
    s.az
    , s.ta
    , s.zamanSarfShode
    , p.name
FROM 
    saateruzane s 
JOIN 
    projhe p 
JOIN 
    kareruzane k
WHERE 
    s.ProjheId = p.id
AND 
    k.id = s.ruzId 
AND 
    k.ruzGregorian = date(now())
```

PHP code :

```
$con->join('projhe p', 's.ProjheId = p.id');
$con->join('kareruzane k', 'k.id = s.ruzId');
$con->joinWhere('kareruzane k','k.ruzGregorian', 'date(now())');
$tines = $con->get('saateruzane s',null,'s.az ,s.ta ,s.zamanSarfShode ,p.name');
```

Comment: You probably can't pass in `'date(now())'` like that, since it may try to quote it. Try passing in `date('Y-m-d')`, without quoting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition for `joinWhere` is

```
public function joinWhere($whereJoin, $whereProp, $whereValue = 'DBNULL', $operator = '=', $cond = 'AND')
```

So you don't need to pass in every part. Instead, try this:

```
$con->joinWhere('kareruzane k','k.ruzGregorian = date(now())');
```

Though better than `date(now())` is `CURDATE()`

```
$con->joinWhere('kareruzane k','k.ruzGregorian = curdate()');
```

However, I'm not sure you should be using a join here, since it's part of the `WHERE` clause on your original query, not the `JOIN` clause. So instead do

```
$con->where('k.ruzGregorian = curdate()');
```

Answer (score 0):

With just a fast look on this lib docs, I found this:

```
'createdAt' => $db->now(),
// createdAt = NOW()
```

https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class#insert-query

In your case try use

```
$con->joinWhere('kareruzane k','k.ruzGregorian', $con->now());
```

Comment: That will compare to a datetime string, instead of the date string the OP wants.